# How to fix this improper rendering in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, rendering

I'm trying to view a distribution of points from inside.

```
 Graphics3D[{Function[s,{Hue[s/180],Point[{Cos[s Degree],##}&@@@CirclePoints[Sin[s Degree],50]]}]/@Range[0,180,10]},ViewVector->{{0,0,0},{.7,0,0}}]
```

If rendered correctly, Mathematica should display a set of red and yellow points in front of the camera positioned at `{0,0,0}`. However, I discovered a set of blue points on the image, which, by theory, should be behind the camera.

If I substitute `Point` with `Sphere`, Mathematica can render the image correctly again! However, render a `Sphere` is much more resource and time-consuming than render a point, thus would deteriorate the performance (especially in the latest version, where rendering is unbelievably slow).

So I would like to ask about how to fix this bug! Thanks!

FYI: Similar issue exists in `Line`, but can be fixed by substituting `Line` by `Tube` as well.

Comment: Do not add the bugs tag until somebody else confirms that this behavior is, indeed, a bug. It would also help greatly if you could include the output you see, with the points you think are erroneous highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

A slight change in the camera x-position, such as `ViewVector->{{0.01,0,0},{.7,0,0}}`, seems to work properly, but not `{0,0,0}`.